Global file pointer in C
I'm having a problem with a global file pointer in C with Visual Studio 2022 in a solution involving a large number of files that are compiled and linked using the "Build" command.
Based on the link at https://codeforwin.org/c-programming/global-variables-c#google_vignette I've created a file called globals.c with the code:
 #include <stdio.h>
 FILE* logFp;

Then in main.c I have the following code:
 #include "main.h"
 extern FILE* logFp;

 int main(void) {
   errno_t fileErr = 0;
   logFp = NULL;
   char logFn[FNAME_LEN] = { 0 };
   printf("Type the output log filename:                                 ");
    scanf_s("%s", logFn, FNAME_LEN);
    fileErr = fopen_s(&logFp, logFn, "w");
    if (fileErr) {
        printf("*** There is an error when attempting to open the log file ***\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int x = 5;
    UINT bits = 255;
    gprint(logFp, 161, "d b b\n", x, bits, 2 * bits);
    gprint(logFp, 1, "d b b\n", x, bits, 2 * bits);
    fclose(logFp);
    return 0;
 }

This is a test part in main() in a large solution with many other files involving the gprint() functions which I know works when logFp is defined locally.
When I attempt to compile this I get a link error that logFp is an unresolved symbol, which I get with other files in the solution containing logFp. Incidentally, main.h is my header file which includes many function prototypes, various defines and macros, as well as a number of includes. The solution works correctly until I try using a global file pointer. Some advice would be most appreciated.

What commands are you running exactly to compile and link?

Did you include globals.o in the link?

If no one has told you before, please try to avoid global variables, especially non-static global variables. Structure your code so global variables aren't needed, mostly by passing data and information as arguments to functions. That will make your code easier to understand and maintain. It will also make it easier if you need reentrancy, as well as separation of concern and abstractions.

My guess is that you are only compiling the file main.c, but not the file globals.c. Did you add the file global.c to your project? It is not sufficient for the file to be inside the project directory; the file must actually be added to the project.

In order to see inside the output window the exact command-line arguments that are being used to invoke the linker, you can deactivate the option "Suppress Startup Banner" in the "General" category of the "Linker" options of the project settings. It would be useful if you posted the content of the output window when building the project, so that we can see exactly how the linker is being invoked. Without this information, I am afraid that your question is unanswerable.

Your problem is that your not using the syntax correctly. What's extern? You're hiding a supposedly global variable in a C file where it gets tucked away. There is no "real" global external variable which is why it results in an unresolved symbol.
The proper way to do it in your case is to externalize your variables in header files (yes, the .h files not the .c files), then initialize them in one of the C file that becomes its "container" object.
Your "main.h" file (I am too lazy to think of a name):
#include <stdio.h>
extern FILE* logFp;

main.c (notice that it's not marked as extern here; why would it be an external variable since we're initializing it?):
 #include "main.h"
 FILE* logFp = NULL;

For short, it not being in a header file where every other piece of code can see it makes it "unresolved" because nobody knows anything about it.
I will not deny I have immense curiosity as to why you want to have the FILE global, though.
I will only close this with a reading recommendation. I think that'll answer just about any question you'll have.

There's no rule against extern declarations in .c files, and you don't have to initialize it where it's defined.

Global variables are always initialized. If you don't have an explicit initialization, then the variable will be "zero initialized", which for pointers are the same as initializing it to NULL.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I didn't say there is. I only said it should be extern in headers if they are initially defined in headers, meaning if he only uses in a .c files, of course, he is free to. But it seems to not be the case here as wants it used across files. Or rather, that is how I always used them as it made the most sense (even if just for readability and following code).

Re “There is no "real" global external variable which is why it results in an unresolved symbol.”: Yes, there is an external variable; OP shows FILE* logFp; defined (via tentative definition) in globals.c. The cause of the unresolved symbol is likely because they failed to include globals.o in the link, not because they do not have a definition in a .c file. (Also, C has no global variables. There are identifiers with file scope and external linkage, which is different.)

OK, many thanks, I tried 2 way: (1): Leave the file globals.c with the code in it linked to the rest of the solution, and in main.c use FILE* logFp; without the extern, and (2) remove globals and place extern FILE* logFp; at the end of main.h., and also have  FILE* logFp; in main.c after #include."main.h" before main(). Both work, but the 2nd is neater. I also found that in another file in my solution I don't need any FILE* logFp; statement at the beginning of the file, and the solution compiles and links correctly. I haven't tried execute it, but it should work.

@csharp The second way is how I recommended and that was my whole point: declaring it in the header that way meant you didn't need to put File* logFp in another file and thus your whole codebase is simplified.
